How to connect a stepper motor to Arduino far away?
What cables would be good for the question in the title, noting that I do not (at least yet) have any soldering/crimping/etc. equipment?
Preface
To start with; I'm a complete beginner, never had anything to do with robotics, and this is my first time touching these things. I know how to code (my main field) and I've handled a little bit some pre-existing machinery somewhat though. Please do not expect me to know the terminology of this field. I've found some components that I could probably use, but after looking through different cables for around 5 hours, I'm starting to feel a bit lost.
Description of the project
I want to build a system that is controlled by an Arduino board. the Arduino board must use 4 'outputs' and 2 'inputs'. As I'm a beginner, I do not have anything to create robotics, so I would like to keep this as simple as possible regarding the equipment needed to build this. This will act similar to a "miniature" CNC-machine, except it will be moving mainly vertically instead of horizontally. In essence the cables will be moving a lot.
Possible limitations
Since the Arduino board will be stationary and not attached to the moving head, the cables need to be long enough to attach to the unit carrying 1-2 of the stepper motors (Z(+Y) axis), which may be around 80cm away from Arduino itself at max. Most of the jumping wires(?) and I2C cables (?) seem to be around 20cm long, and people keep mentioning that longer cables induce noise or loss in voltage. Because of this I'm starting to doubt that either of those cables would be a good idea for this purpose, at least on their own.
Requirements and used components
Inputs

1 wifi thing to receive coordinates to move to through wifi somehow
1 obstacle detector thing using a laser

Outputs

1 stepper motor for X axis control
1 stepper motor for Y axis control
1 stepper motor for Z axis control
(I've been looking at these https://eu.robotshop.com/products/5-vdc-stepper-motor-with-uln2003-driver-board )
1 fan thing to control air pressure to be either positive or negative
(probably gonna pick something from a broken laptop)

essentially -> 3-dimensionally moving fan with no rotation.
Maximum moving distances for the axis

X: 50cm
Y: 80cm
Z: 80cm
Fan: 80cm
Total movable loads: probably 100-200g depending on how heavy the axis will be.
I assume the distance can be covered by either the cables between the control board and motor, or Arduino and control board.

Extras, I (probably) won't be burning my home down
I know that the stepper motors and fan cannot be directly connected to the Arduino board. The only thing that I don't know is that what kind of power supply I need to have to connect those (and also how to connect the ps to the motors). I'm assuming that I can power the Arduino board using the same ps for what I've read of the specs though. I'll probably be using a bread board for these connections if I deem it to be safe and secure to do so.
